# Why does the state not update

Tags: reactjs, cookies, use-effect, use-state

When a new user visits page, they can fill in an username, which is stored in state and in a cookie. I later want to access that cookie and state to identify username in a game session, however they are both empty at that point, even though I know they have been set (logging sees the values, the username is correctly displayed in the header). Why is that happening?

```
const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["username"]);
const [formerUsername, setFormerUsername] = useState(cookies.username ? cookies.username : null);
...

function handleUsernameChange(username) {
        setCookie("username", username, {path: "/", expires: expirationDate});
        setFormerUsername(username);
        ...
    }
    
useEffect(() => {
        ...
socket.on(TRANSMISSIONS.startGame, data => {
            let playerIndex = data.room.players.indexOf(cookies.username);
            history.push({pathname: "/game", data: {username: cookies.username, room: data.room, playerIndex: playerIndex,
                    }});
        });
```

The player index is -1, because cookies.username is undefined. I know that it is set because I a) see the cookie, b) see the username loaded from the cookie in the header of the page.

So why is it shown as undefined here? The same goes for the useState, which shows initial value (`null`), not the actual value...

EDIT: complete code is here - https://github.com/faire2/loreHunters/blob/master/src/components/loginPage/LoginPage.js

The code is live at arnak-dev.herokuapp.com.

[image]

Comment: "When a new user visits page, he can fill in an username" -  what if your visitor is female?

Comment: If you use an effect to simply log changes to `cookies` do you see it update in your component? Can you include a more complete component example? What is *all* of that effect with the `socket` doing? I suspect you've closed over your `cookies` value in the `startGame` callback.

Comment: Agree with @DrewReese - you need to add more code to show a more complete example. What does the `useCookies` hook do?

Comment: @DrewReese I added links to code and live application. Yes I see the update in the component. The use effect is for connection to server and back through Socket.IO.

Comment: @gerrod I have added links to code and live app. The useEffect connects client to server through Socket.IO (which is necessary to facilitate multiplayer element of the game).

Comment: @Dai what term would you use? They?

Comment: @Faire Yup, _singular they_, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_languages_with_gendered_third-person_pronouns

Comment: `cookies.username` won't be defined yet when you `useState(cookies.username ? cookies.username : null);`, and your `useEffect` runs only once upon component mount. You've no effect to update any socket details when the `cookies` state updates.

Comment: @DrewReese I generally understand that. However I though that the situation is different with transmissions - my understanding is that I create an even listener which is triggered when the transmission is received. In this case I click on the button to start a game, which sends transmission back to server. Server processess the request, starts game, and sends data back to users. `socket.on(TRANSMISSIONS.startGame` receives transmission and processes it. According to you it is processed always with the original state? Is there a way to update the listener?

Comment: Right, you've a few issues I think. First, yes, it appears you've closed over your initial `cookies` state in the `socket` event handlers since the `useEffect` has an empty dependency array. Second, in several of your functions you call `setCookie` but then a line or two later emit the ***current*** `cookie.username` value (not the one just queued for the *next* render cycle). Third, (*well I guess related to first*) your effect doesn't return a clean up function to (A) disconnect/close any open sockets and (B) reenclose the updated `cookies` state value in the event handlers.

Comment: @DrewReese I have actually already added the dependencies, the change is not yet pushed to repository: `[cookies.username, expirationDate, history, setCookie, shakedHand]);` It didn't help, once in the TRANSMISSIONS.startGame, cookie is undefined and `formerUsername` null. I am only calling `setCookie` in useEffect to extend its validity and only if it is defined, so that probably works. Which lefts the last part. How should the cleanup look like? I need to keep the socket open until I change the location, is that right?

Comment: Either the socket needs to remain open until you navigate to the new route, or at a minimum, unregister the event handlers added by the login page component. This you likely want in a mounting effect with a returned cleanup function. I think to resolve your main issue with the `cookies` value you need to define the socket callbacks that *depend* on `cookies` external to the effect hook. If you want I can provide an example as answer.

Comment: @DrewReese I would be really grateful for that! I have already included a very basic clean-up:
`return () =>  socket.disconnect();`, but I have no idea how to resolve the cookie / useState problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. Stale enclosures in callbacks, and misplaced effect dependency array

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     // extend cookie if it exists
     ...

     socket.on(TRANSMISSIONS.startGame, data => {
       let playerIndex = data.room.players.indexOf(cookies.username);
       history.push({
         pathname: "/game",
         data: {
           username: cookies.username, // <-- value when effect ran
           room: data.room,
           playerIndex: playerIndex,
         },
       });
     });

     ...

     socket.on(TRANSMISSIONS.currentUsersAndData, data => {
       console.log("received actual room and users data");
       if (!shakedHand) { // <-- stale
           setShakedHand(true)
       }
       setUsers(data.users);
       setRooms(data.rooms);
       setRoomIsFull(false);
     }, []) // <-- dependency array
   });
   ```
2. Accessing state from the wrong render cycle

   ```
   function handleUsernameChange(username) {
     setCookie("username", username, {path: "/", expires: expirationDate});
     setFormerUsername(username);

     if (!formerUsername) { // <-- current formerUsername state
       socket.emit(
         TRANSMISSIONS.handShake,
         cookies.username, // <-- current cookies state
       );
     } else {
       socket.emit(
         TRANSMISSIONS.usernameChanged,
         {
           formerUsername: formerUsername, // <-- current formerUsername state
           newUsername: username, // <-- current username state
         },
       );
     }

     setShowCreateUsername(false);
   }
   ```

## Suggestions

I think these changes should get your code to a better place, but there may be some tweaking to do with dependencies and conditional tests.

1. Fix stale enclosure by declaring the callback *outside* the effect. The idea here is `onStartGameHandler` is defined each render cycle and encloses the current state.

   ```
   const onStartGameHandler = data => {
     const playerIndex = data.room.players.indexOf(cookies.username);
     history.push({
       pathname: "/game",
       data: {
         username: cookies.username,
         room: data.room,
         playerIndex: playerIndex,
       },
     });
   };

   const onUsersAndDataHandler = data => {
     console.log("received actual room and users data");
     if (!shakedHand) {
       setShakedHand(true)
     }
     setUsers(data.users);
     setRooms(data.rooms);
     setRoomIsFull(false);
   }

   useEffect(() => {
     // extend cookie if it exists
     if (cookies.username && !shakedHand) { ...

     ...

     socket.on(TRANSMISSIONS.startGame, onStartGameHandler);

     ...

     socket.on(TRANSMISSIONS.currentUsersAndData, onUsersAndDataHandler);

     // return clean up function
     return () => socket.off(TRANSMISSIONS.startGame);
   }, []);
   ```
2. Fix state accesses by "reacting" to state update in a separate effect triggered *by* the updated state variables as dependencies.

   ```
   function handleUsernameChange(username) {
     setCookie("username", username, {path: "/", expires: expirationDate});
     setFormerUsername(username);
     setShowCreateUsername(false);
   }

   ...

   useEffect(() => {
     if (!formerUsername) {
       socket.emit(TRANSMISSIONS.handShake, cookies.username);
     } else {
       socket.emit(
         TRANSMISSIONS.usernameChanged,
         {
           formerUsername: formerUsername,
           newUsername: username,
         },
       );
     }
   }, [cookies, formerUsername, username]);
   ```

Comment: I have implemented both changes you offered, but the same error still occures. I have pushed your changes to the repo so you can see them, you can also check the things live at http://arnak-dev.herokuapp.com/game. What I understand even less is that `if (cookies.username && !shakedHand)` part of useEffect registers the new cookie at once.

I am stupified.

Comment: @Faire I've played around a bit with your app on heroku, it appears to work for up until opening a game, but TBH I'm stumbling in the dark. I see the `formerUsername` state update to my username, cookies set. I think I see the `shakedHand` state not updating. Can you provide reproduction steps?

Comment: The reproduction is 100%:
1. no cookie exists. 2. create new username. 3. without refresh create a new game and start it. It will crash because it will be unable to determine the user.

Comment: But it seems that the transmissions always trigger the useState effect that was created when the page was initialized. I changed the code so that I pass username explicitly to startGame function with logging. I see that the username is correctly pased to the function (debugger shows that the new username is known to the useEffect), but as soon as it reaches the startGame function the username is undefined again.

Comment: Logging shows that the startGame function is in fact ran twice - first with undefind username, then (too late) with a defined one.

Comment: And finally, I have the solution. I needed to sign off from the socket listener when the state change. `return () => socket.off(TRANSMISSIONS.startGame);` is all it took, I mean apart of hours of trials and errors. Thanks so much, your responses helped me go into the right direction. Would you like to update your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Faire Great! I did update my answer to include the specific effect cleanup. Let me know if this is now sufficient.